# How to determine which points (x,y) out of million data points lie inside the area described by a rectangle (x1, x2, y1, y2)?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, quadtree

I need to figure out how to check if certain points lie inside or outside a rectangle given as coordinates (x1,x2,y1,y2) i.e. top left and bottom right points of rectangle. The total number of points are pretty large approx. 2 million. I know a quadtree is used in such cases but I can't seem to figure out how to apply that here. Like what to store in the tree and how to query it.

Also if someone can help me understand how to solve this problem for a small number of points efficiently then that would be great too !

Comment: Have you tried anything other than a quadtree then? Add whatever approach you've tried.

Comment: Describe usage case. Do point set change often? Are rectangles fixed? Any details?

Comment: Are the points organized somehow ? Or are they in a random order ?

Comment: Is this a one-time thing? That is, are you given a list of points and a static rectangle? Or is it something that you'll want to query multiple times with different rectangles? The former is a simple O(n) traversal of a list. The latter is ... more complex.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have all the n points stored statically in a random order and want to process them, there is nothing better than a linear search checking the condition for each point (the only improvement you can do is to put processes and threads to parcel different blocks of the array of points).

If you receive them dynamically, you can store them in a quadtree as you receive. Then you can search in logarithmic time in n (in average) for the quantity of points in a rectangle.

Comment: Yes I'm going to receive them dynamically, but I can't figure out how to check whether some points lie inside a rectangle using a quad tree structure of points

Comment: The idea is that you store the count for all subrectangles with height H/2^m and width W/2^m (until the smallest unit you want), starting from a rectangle with dimensions H and W that you know can contain all the points. These subrectangles will be the nodes of the quadtree. Whenever you insert a point, you need to update the count of O(log n) rectangles in average. Then, you can calculate the count for any subrectangle with dimensions h and w by traversing O(log n) nodes of the quadtree in average. I suggest you to try visualizing with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

Quad trees are quite easy and worth it.

However a simple solution (sufficient but not that good):

You can also sort the points in two lists

- Sorted by x
- Sorted by y

Say you have two lists of both 10_000 points.
For an x matching you get 200 points,
for an y matching you get 80 points.

A matching is done by the two rectangle boundary coordinates: (left, right) resp. (top, bottom). With binary search O(log n).

Insertion of a new point can also be done with binary search.

The intersection of both results lies exactly inside your rectangle.

---

***An untested 5 minute implementation***

```
List<Point> points = ...;
SortedSet<Point> pointsByX =
    new TreeSet<>(points, Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getX)
                                    .thenComparingInt(Point::getY));
SortedSet<Point> pointsByY =
    new TreeSet<>(points, Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getY)
                                    .thenComparingInt(Point::getX));

Set<Point> pointsInRect(Rectangle rect) {
     Point minXMinY = new Point(rect.x, rect.y);
     Point maxXMaxY = new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);
     Set<Point> pointsX = pointsByX.subSet(minXMinY, maxXMaxY);
     Set<Point> pointsY = pointsByY.subSet(minXMinY, maxXMaxY);
     Set<Point> rectPoints = new HashSet<>(pointsY);
     rectPoints.retainAll(pointsX);
     return rectPoints;
}
```

Implemented to demonstrate the Comparator & subTree usage.

Comment: Thankyou ! That's what I was looking for. So if I were to use Quad Trees, how should I proceed ? I mean I should make a tree of all the given points and then query their intersection with the rectangle correct ? But how would I query that is something I can't wrap my head around. Would it be possible to share an example implementation of that ? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-range-search or https://gist.github.com/AbhijeetMajumdar/c7b4f10df1b87f974ef4

Comment: Thankyou so much ! Just one more thing, so I've been trying to implement the sorting solution for sometime now but I keep getting stuck. I use 2 TreeSet<Point>, one sorted on x and one on y. But I'm not sure how to intersect them with rectangle range. I tried set.subSet(xMin,xMax) but since xMin is integer and set has Point object this is obviously not working. Any tips on what I can try ? Thanks !

Comment: @sweet_summer_child added an implementation. It is remarkable how simple it looks.